# VB get text from html element

Tags: vb.net

I need to get the text between two span tags on a web page using visual basic.

```
<span>Some Text</span>
```

I know there must be a way but I can't seem to find it.

This is for a website i do not own.

Answer (score 1):

Give your span an ID and `runat="server"` attribute e.g.

```
<span id="xMySpan" runat="server">Some Text</span>
```

Then you will be able to retrieve it in server-side code, e.g.

```
Dim sVar As String = xMySpan.InnerHtml
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want to do some screen scrapping?

Answer (score 0):

What about assigning an ID to the span? If you do, then this works:

```
TextBox1.Text = _
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("spanID").GetAttribute("innerText")
```

Using this format:

```
<span id="spanID">...</span>
```

EDIT: To filter by content:

```
$("span").filter(function(){
    return $(this).html() == "a";
})
```

Will work with this:

```
<span>a</span>
```

Comment: The span i am  trying to select does have an id, but i need to select it by the text inside the span tags

Comment: well anyway to do this without editing the html document @Eric?

Comment: I did not really understand that

Answer (score 0):

Are you extracting this from the entire HTML document or just the quoted text above?

If its just the above (and you've already filtered out the other HTML) then you can use a conbination of LEFT() and RIGHT() to snip off the ends, or use REPLACE() to get rid of the two tags.

Comment: I am trying to get the text externally from an entire document

Answer (score 0):

I made this script, hope it will be helpful

I have:

- Textbox to get the youtube url [urlVideo]
- Button to load the page [btn_loadViews]
- A webBrowser Control [webBrowser1]
- and a label to show the text [lb_views]

I'm not validating anything, so This is just an example of how do i get text from websites.
If there's another way to do it, i would like to know it too. =)

```
Private Sub btn_loadViews_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_loadViews.Click

    WebBrowser1.Navigate(urlVideo.Text)
    WaitForPageLoad()

    getViews()


End Sub

Private Sub getViews()
    Try
        Dim version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("c:\windows\system32\ieframe.dll")
        'Depending on the navigator version, google's server sends diffetent pages, so
        'Here Detect ie version
        If version.ProductVersion < "8" Then
            lb_views.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("vc").FirstChild.InnerText
        Else
            lb_views.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("watch7-views-info").FirstChild.InnerText
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Application.Exit()
    End Try

End Sub


Private Property pageready As Boolean = False

Private Sub WaitForPageLoad()
    AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New     WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    While Not pageready
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    pageready = False
End Sub

Private Sub PageWaiter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        pageready = True
        RemoveHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim WithEvents hDoc As HTMLDocument
Set hDoc = WebBrowser1.Document
Dim strValue As String
strValue = hDoc.getElementsByName("so").Item(0).Value
```