# Regex to extract url from a div with variable class name

Tags: vb.net

I need to extract the url from a div with variable class name using regex, can somebody help please?, this is what i have so far:

```
  Dim wc As New WebClient
  Dim source As String = wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.es/search?num=100&q=short hair dogs")
  Dim m1 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(source, "http(s?)://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+", RegexOptions.Singleline + RegexOptions.IgnoreCase + RegexOptions.Compiled)
  For Each m As Match In m1
      If Not m.Value.Contains("google") Then
          ListBox1.Items.Add(m.Groups(0).Value)
          Label1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count
      End If
  Next
```

div is:

```html
<div class="variable class name here">http(s)://somedomainname.com</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your posted code as code format so we can read it

Comment: it's easier if you use the webbrowser control, this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934566/vb-get-text-from-html-element

Comment: and i think this is a duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686488/getting-contents-of-specific-div-element